# Service Discovery within Kubernetes

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, azure-aks

When deploying a set of SpringBoot microservice applications in a Kubernetes cluster, should I include any kind of service discovery client libraries in my SpringBoot application to leverage kubernetes-native-service-discovery? If not, how a caller service calls another microservice in the same cluster?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A service in kubernetes can be invoked as mentioned below for example an http service. An service has to be created and associated with pod.  Please refer kubernetes [services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) documentation for various services.

```
http://<service-name>:<port>
```

No other changes are required from application end.  Please refer [kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/) official documentation for resolution details

Comment: Is Spring Cloud Discovery Client needed even when using Kubernetes Native Service Discovery in AKS while deploying Spring Boot applications ?

Comment: It wouldn’t be required as K8S native service discovery will suffice.  Discovery feature is used by spring cloud ribbon project and discovery server.   spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-discoveryclient is designed to be used with the Spring Cloud Kubernetes DiscoveryServer.  https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-kubernetes/docs/current/reference/html/#kubernetes-native-service-discovery